# Store read-only calculated field with Entity Framework Code First

Tags: ef-code-first, entity-framework-4.1

I am using Entity Framework Code First, and I have an entity defined with a `StartTime` property, an `EndTime` property and a `Duration` property (along with some others).  The `Duration` property is a calculated field and it is the duration in minutes between the start and end time.  My property declarations are shown below:

```
public DateTime StartTime { get; set; }
public DateTime EndTime { get; set; }
public int Duration
{
    get
    {
        return (int)this.EndTime.Subtract(this.StartTime).TotalMinutes;
    }
}
```

I would like to run this calculation in code, but have the duration value persisted to the database along with the start and end time values (to make it easier later down the line when I come to run reports against these figures).

My question is, how can I get this read-only property to map back and save to the database using code first?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Inspired by Slauma's answer, I was able to achieve what I was aiming for by using a protected setter.  This persisted the value back to the database but didn't allow the value to be modified elsewhere.

My property now looks like this:

```
public int Duration
{
    get
    {
        return (int)this.EndTime.Subtract(this.StartTime).TotalMinutes;
    }
    protected set {}
}
```

Comment: Ah, good idea to make it protected! Did you also try to make the setter `private`? Would be interesting to know if EF will map then the property to a DB column.

Comment: I have just tried with a `private` setter and surprisingly it continues to work!

Comment: EF will update the database every time this entity is loaded. We guess that EF's change tracking mistakenly believes this property has changed. For us, this caused unexpected concurrency conflicts.

Comment: "mistakenly"?  I think not. If you load the entity into the change tracker, and then you call save changes, and the change tracker does  what it's supposed to do and check whether the *current* value matches the database value for each object... it will see that the just-computed current value differs and will save the object.  That's exactly how it's supposed to work and isn't a mistake.

Answer (score 2):

Supplying an empty setter might be a possible solution (although then the property isn't readonly anymore, of course):

```
public int Duration
{
    get
    {
        return (int)this.EndTime.Subtract(this.StartTime).TotalMinutes;
    }
    set { }
}
```

As far as I know, readonly properties are not mappable to a column in the database.