# Proper way to have an calculated field in EF Code First

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, calculated-columns

I referenced this question on SO:

[Store read-only calculated field with Entity Framework Code First](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5663488/store-read-only-calculated-field-with-entity-framework-code-first)

What they are doing makes sense, but I am trying something a little different and am not sure if my implementation is proper, or if there is any easier way to do this:

```
public class AffiliateCommission
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Merchant Merchant { get; set; }
    public AffiliateCommissionType Type { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public int Amount { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
    public DateTime RecievedDate { get; set; }
    public int TotalPaid { get 
    {
        if (Status == "Paid")
        {
            return this.Amount += this.Amount;
        }
        return 0;
    }
        protected set { }
    }


    public int TotalUnpaid
    {
        get
        {
            if (Status == "Unpaid")
            {
                return this.Amount += this.Amount;
            }
            return 0;
        }
        protected set { }
    }
    public int TotalInvoiced
    {
        get
        {
            if (Status == "Invoiced")
            {
                return this.Amount += this.Amount;
            }
            return 0;
        }
        protected set { }
    }
}
```

There is going to be a list of AffiliateCommissions, and I want to get the total of all the commissions based off of status. Store it in a different Model maybe? Need some implementation advise.

Answer (score 2):

Why are you trying to persist a calculated field? With the calculation logic in a property, you could just leave the property as transient and have it calculated on the fly every time. That way there is no need to persist it. Your calculations do not seem to be very expensive. This approach also has the advantage of your calculated values always being accurate, in the case of your business logic changing.

One use case for having calculated fields persisted is for reporting you want to pull straight from the database. If this is the case, I would recommend looking into mapreduce queries instead: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MapReduce

Comment: OK, yeah I don't need this for any heavy reporting or anything, so maybe I am looking at the solution incorrectly. I am just trying to figure out the best route to pull in a set of AffiliateCommisions in my asp.net MVC controller, return that list the the view, and have the sum of certain records available to me on the view in an easy manner, preferrably avoiding js. Sorry if this doesn't make sense. Been on a coding death march and it is 1am currently.

Comment: @davidisawesome If you are using a strongly typed view, then you should be able to access your calculated properties like any other. If not, you could use a view model instead. Maybe your properties are not calculating what you really want though - at the moment it looks like `TotalUnpaid` will always look at this.Amount for the current record only. If you're trying to sum values across records, then this class is probably not the place for it

Answer (score 1):

I like EF Code First but I don't actually "code first".  I'll typically create the schema in the database and use the EF Code First Powertool to reverse engineer.  The Code First is lighter weight, but the whole database upgrade process can be painful, in development and production, so I've found it easier to maintain the DB the old school way and reverse engineer to get my entities.

You could try this approach, create the calculated field in the SQL Server, and reverse engineer it to see what code gets generated.

Comment: I agree, I had a lot of pain trying to code first when I had existing data. I supposed the right way to do this would to be to insert the data through our project (if migrating). Having to recreate the models over and over every database table change is quiet a pain too though.