# How to make a calculated property to persist in database in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

Consider this simple class:

```
puclic class Person
{
    public string FirstName {get; set; }
    public string LastName {get; set; }

    public string FullName
    {
        get
        {
            return FirstName + " " + LastName;
        }
    }
}
```

I want the to have `FullName` column in database too with its corresponding value.

**Question:** How can I say to Entity Framework 6 to consider a calculated property as a column?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5663488/store-read-only-calculated-field-with-entity-framework-code-first the answer is here, possible duplicate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can be add empty **protected setter**.

```
public string FullName
{
    get
    {
        return FirstName + " " + LastName;
    }
    protected set {}
}
```